# Basis and cardinality

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, schauder-basis, hamel-basis

Suppose that $B$ is a separable Hilbert space and $\{b_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a countable linearly independent set.  Then is $\{b_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ necessarily a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) for $B$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously not, because for example any subset is also independent, but a proper subset of a basis cannot be a basis.

Comment: Sorry there wsa a typo.  I mean't a countable linearly independent set.

Comment: @N00ber ??? It was clear that you were talking about a countable independent set - what does that have to do with the answer I gave?

Comment: Oh I tried to accept both but that can't be done.  It's good now :)

Answer (score 4):

No. For example, the sequence 
$$\begin{align} b_0 &= (1,0,0,0,0,\dots)\\ b_1 &= (0,0,1,0,0,\dots)\\ b_2 &= (0,0,0,0,1,\dots)\\ \vdots &= \vdots \end{align}$$

is linearly independent in $\ell^2$, but not a Schauder basis. ($b_n$ has a $1$ in position $2n$ and zeros elsewhere.)

Comment: Very clear answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Besides taking a proper subset of a Schauder basis, you can also take a superset that is still (algebraically) linearly independent.  For instance, if $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis, then $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cup\{v\}$ is still linearly independent where $v=\sum_n e_n/2^n$, but is not a Schauder basis since the representation of $v$ as an infinite linear combination of basis elements is not unique.

Comment: Wait, so every countable linearly-independent subset of $B$ cannot be "extended" to a Schauder basis of $B$?